# Is it possible to display a message in an adjacent cell on Excel if there are ANY exact matches on the sheet?

Tags: database, excel

I wouldn't say I was a complete beginner on Excel but I really can't work this out.

I'm putting together a database where if two cell values (alphanumeric) are the same, I need to be made aware.

So is there any formula that I can apply that will display the cell letter/number that has ANY exact match on the page. I.E:

C4 value is AEP314890 and I enter the same value in K9. Is there a formula that will display 'C4 MATCH' in cell L9?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: You'd have to write some code, I'd imagine. You'd also have to be careful that the code that triggers when the cell changes doesn't get a circular reference.

Comment: @MattFowkes .. have you try the answers ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the countif function

```
=COUNTIF(B4:C7,F7)    -> apply this in for example cell D4
```

Where `B4:C7` is your range and `F7` is the value that you want to compare. Now a second step would be a new `IF` to check if the value of `D4` is higher than 0, then you can assume there exists the number already:

```
=IF(D4>0,"Found","not Found")
```

[image: Example]

This would be the first step, now if you want to know where it is the same, you compare it with the Values simply.

Answer (score 0):

Match() can help you, 
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match_function.php

it returns the index of the matched cell in a range...

lets say
A |  B
v1|v2
v3|v4
v5|v6

D1 = 'v5'   E1 = `Match(A1..B5, D1)` = 5

you can then use then to find the Column Name and Row Name

Answer (score 0):

> C4 value is AEP314890 and I enter the same value in K9. Is there a
>   formula that will display 'C4 MATCH' in cell L9?

Just put this formula in your L9 Column .. assumed you search in C1:C100 ..

```
= If(Isna(Match(K9,$C$1:$C$100,0)),"","C" & TEXT(Match(K9,$C$1:$C$100,0),"###") & " Match !")
```

Comment: He was giving an example of a possible situation. I believe he wants to know if C4 matches **any** other records, and furthermore, if any cell matches any other cell.